# AWS CodeBuild - Change branch dynamically

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I am building CI/CD process using CodeBuild and I'd like to have tests run when pull requet is created (I'm using Bitbucket). As I can see I'm able to set up a trigger when pull requests from branch `feature/{xxx}` is created but also I have to make CodeBuild to checkout to the branch `feature/{xxx}`. There is input for `Source version` but I can't put there anything parameterized. How to do it the right way? Or how to do it at all?

Answer (score 1):

If your buildspec is static between branches, then you can do a `checkout` in the buildspec to switch to files from the commit that initiated the webhook.

Use commands like, e.g.

```
git checkout $CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_HEAD_REF
```

Tip: Use printenv in the buildspec to check for available CodeBuild variables and what suits to get the required commit.

- Environment variables in build environments  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html